# How to skip HTTPS redirection, only if the url contains a substring?

Tags: apache, redirect, https

In my Apache http.conf file, I have the following redirect setup, which means that if I access an endpoint using my server's domain name, it serves its HTTPS equivalent, instead of HTTP. However there's a particular URL where I do not want this address to occur. This is how i've got it set up at the moment:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/srv/httpd"
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

So what do I need to add, so that if I were to access http://example.com/insecure/ (and anything within that folder), it doesn't redirect me anywhere, however it does redirect to HTTPS if i'm accessing anything else on my domain? Just a second RewriteCond? I'm not sure of the syntax

Answer (score 0):

I've added a second RewriteCond of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/insecure/` which seems to have done the job.